# jumping with Ctrl-] in vim does not work

Tags: vim

I am working with vim on debian.
When I press `ctrl-]` vim beeps, inserts a new line and goes to "visual block". It does not jump to tag.  The same happens with `:ctrl-]`. Even in insert-mode with `ctrl-]` vim exits from insert-mode, insert new line and goes to 'visual block'.

But when I use such lines in .vimrc

`nnoremap <F3> <c-]>`

`vnoremap <F3> <c-]>`

jumping with F3 works.

Command `:verbose map c-]` returns `No mapping found`

**update:**
As we have discovered in insert mode we can see how vim is interpreting `<c-]>`. In insert mode after `<c-V><c-]>` the correct output should be `^]` . But my output is

```
t
^C
```

Screenshots: after `<c-v>` I get [image]

And after `<c-v><c-]>` [image].

So vim isn't receiving the keystrokes properly. How to check what changes input?

Comment: Have you checked that vim is actually seeing `ctrl-]`? Maybe your terminal or shell is trapping that key combination. I'm not sure how to check it directly; try using it outside of vim.

Comment: How to check it? 

In insert mode bracket ] is inserterted == ] works . And `ctrl-T` jumps back == ctrl works.

`alias` in linux has nothing like `ctrl-]`

Comment: What is in your `.vimrc`? Did one of your coworkers prank you and add some funny mapping in there?

Comment: @SKulibin If you type `<c-v><c-]>` in insert mode you should see how vim is interpreting `<c-]>`. The correct output should be `^]` if you see something else vim isn't receiving the keystrokes properly.

Comment: _What is in your .vimrc?_ - there are nothing with `c-]`. And as I mentioned _Command :verbose map c-] returns No mapping found_

Comment: _@SKulibin If you type <c-v><c-]> in insert mode you should see how vim is interpreting <c-]>. The correct output should be ^] if you see something else vim isn't receiving the keystrokes properly. –  @FDinoff_ - My output is `t
^C`.  Screenshots: after <c-v> I get http://beethe.ru/upload/temp/1.jpg, and after <c-v><c-]> http://beethe.ru/upload/temp/2.jpg. How to check what can change input?

Answer (score 1):

- try running `vim -u NONE` to check if that's happening without any configuration, that way you can be sure it's not a mapping or misconfiguration.

  - if that solves the issue, check your vim configuration!
- Also try doing it in `gvim` and `gvim -u NONE` to narrow down the issue to what it's very likely to be. If that works it's a shell or terminal misconfiguration.

  - if it still fails in the windowed GUI of vim, that means this is X that is wrong, try using `xev` to see what your key outputs, and `xmodmap` to printout the values assigned to all your keys on your keyboard layout.
- Try using another terminal (like `urxvt`, `gnome-terminal`, `xterm` or the raw linux console), to determine whether it's a terminal emulator misconfiguration of your keys or if it's your shell.

  - if it's your terminal emulator, then get through the configuration or reset its configuration, there's something setup that shouldn't have been.
- Try changing shell to see if that improves (by I doubt it will)… And add the following configuration files in your home directory:

.inputrc

```
Tab: complete
set meta-flag on
set input-meta on
set output-meta on
set convert-meta off
```

If that's not enough, you might want to check as well you `stty` settings for your current shell as well.

If none of that helps, then… take a big hammer and hit very hard your keyboard and your computer, that won't solve your situation, but you'll feel better!

[image: hammer computer]

HTH

Comment: `vim -u NONE` and gvim did nothing. But I think that the reason is in terminal. I use putty for windows to connect to server. And if I enter `ctrl-]` in command line, I get `root@Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal ~ # ^C` . So I think that putty trapping key combination.

Comment: Aaaah! You said you were using debian, not putty. Then it might a special key caught by putty. And my last comment totally applies, as then you wouldn't harm the sweet debian ;-)

Comment: How to see symbols send by keys? I have tried `od -a` , but on  `ctrl-]` it exits (very likely to `ctrl-C`).

Comment: it's because your issue is within the configuration of putty sending the wrong keycode over the terminal session, you cannot debug it *within* the terminal session, but by changing your putty configuration. Sadly, there's little I can do to help, as I'm not a windows user and I don't have putty installed.